# "Task exception on worker thread" issue when integrate Firebase to my App

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

When I try to integrate `Firebase` to my App, I meet a problem.
Previous condition, Google Analytic, Google Map, Google Push are working well with my app. Since google release the `Firebase` with all tools integrated and some new tools, I want to replace them with Firebase.
After replace `google-services.json` and modify `build.gradle` of module and project, compile is ok. But when I try to log an event, I get this error log:

```
12-01 16:10:47.571 V/FA      (30278): onActivityCreated
12-01 16:10:47.654 W/FA      (30278): Failed to invoke Tag Manager's initialize() method: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzac.zzg(Unknown Source)
12-01 16:10:47.655 D/FA      (30278): Logging event (FE): eventName, Bundle[{_o=app, IMEI=354110070069074, SerialNumber=SerialNumber, LenovoId=LenovoId}]
12-01 16:10:47.657 V/FA      (30278): State of service unknown
12-01 16:10:47.657 V/FA      (30278): Checking service availability
12-01 16:10:47.657 E/FA      (30278): Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad.zzbyb(Unknown Source)
12-01 16:10:47.658 V/FA      (30278): Activity paused, time: 509442340
12-01 16:10:47.805 V/FA      (30278): Activity resumed, time: 509442608
```

In fact, that meta-data already exist in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Since the one of Analytics, Map and Push need it, it was added before.

Comment: Post your project and module build.gradle files.